# Is there a limit to the string size that a SwiftUI Text view can display in iOS?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm working on an app that will generate a list of anagrams from a set of input letters. (among other things.)

It's a Multiplatform SwiftUI app.

I just discovered that when running on the iOS 15 simulator, the `Text` field that displays the resulting list of anagram words "blanks out" and fails to display the list of words when the length of the text gets too long (somewhere around 128,575 characters.)

Granted this is an edge case, but I found the problem when generating anagrams from the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", something a user might do.

The results are quite similar when running on my iPhone 15 pro (with the thresholds being slightly different.) Both the sim and the phone are running iOS 17.x. (The sim is iOS 17.0, the phone is running 17.1.2)

The same app doesn't have this problem when build as a Mac app. (or at least I haven't found it.)

The threshold where the text view shows nothing seems to vary slightly, and also depend on the text being displayed. If I sort the list of words longest to shortest, it might fail to show its contents, and if I instead sort the list shortest to longest, it is able to display. That makes me think it has to to with word wrapping and the size of the `Text` view in its `ScrollView`, but I'm really not sure.

The `Text` field is wrapped in a `ScrollView`, and tied to an `@Pubished` variable from a state object for the Anagrams view:

```
                        ScrollView() {
                            Text(anagramsState.wordList)
                                .lineLimit(nil)
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width - 2, minHeight: 20, alignment: .topLeading)
                        }
```

I don't know if it's a memory issue, a rectangle size overflow, or something else.

It's a bit hard to post a minimal reproducible example since this is an app I am planning to sell. I'll have to work on that.

Are any of you aware of the limits on how much text a SwiftUI `Text` field can display on iOS devices?

Comment: Not aware of any limit specifically, but I'd definitely recommend splitting it into chunks and using a `LazyVGrid` inside the `ScrollView` to display them.

Comment: No limits officially but it is well know that there is a point where it just isn’t performant and you have to use uikit

Comment: I haven't see any docs about this but it seems like a limit. Do you need a workaround or just need to make sure?

Comment: I'd like a work-around.

Comment: @loremipsum it doesn't just seem to have poor performance - the Text view goes blank.

Comment: I originally switched to a Text view instead of a TextField because I don't want the results list to be editable. It would be nice if I could make my TextField scrollable and selectable but not editable like I can in UIKit, but I couldn't figure out how to make that work.

Comment: Tapping into UIKit is the most efficient workaround this has come up a few times on SO.

Comment: @loremipsum I haven't tackled wrapping UIKit components in SwiftUI yet. Can you suggest good examples to study? (I know, I'm breaking a major SO rule asking for outside resources...)

Comment: lol, Apple SwiftUI tutorials there is an “Interfacing with UIKit” tutorial and you know I would write it for you but you never accept answers even when I entertain edit after edit, expansion after expansion.

Comment: "...you never accept answers even when I entertain edit after edit..." What? You wound me, sir!